# Execute Shell-Command over python using subprocess

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

when I execute a command (while true; do date; sleep 1; done) over a Python-Skript nothing is displyed and no logging.

```
import logging
import sys
import subprocess as SP


logger = logging.getLogger('logging')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

if not logger.handlers:
    log_handler = logging.FileHandler('test_logging.log')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(log_handler)
    log_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

command = 'while true; do date; sleep 1; done'
p = SP.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=SP.PIPE, stderr=SP.PIPE)
print p.stdout.readlines()

for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    logger.info(line)
    print line
```

Answer (score 1):

`p.stdout.readlines()` tries to read all the lines of the command's output in a list, which will never finish since the command is an infinite loop: `'while true; do date; sleep 1; done'`.

If you're using Python 2, one way of iterating over the lines of the output could be:

```
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print line.rstrip()
```

In Python 3 you can simply iterate over the `p.stdout` file object.

Comment: This just hangs if using Python 2 (as implied by print syntax) on an Ubuntu 14.04 box.  It works if I use Python 3.  I don't know enough about the internals of `subprocess.PIPE` to speculate on why.

Comment: @J Richard: Indeed, iterating over the file object doesn't seem to work in Python 2. I've updated the post with a working version.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (on Python 2.6.6)

```
import subprocess as SP
command = 'while true; do date; sleep 1; done'
p = SP.Popen(command, shell=True, bufsize=1, stdout=SP.PIPE, stderr=SP.PIPE)
while True:
    print p.stdout.readline()
```

The `bufsize=1` isn't essential, but it turns on line buffering, which should improve the efficiency a little.

Comment: @eugeney: Then it's probably better to use one of the convenience functions, eg `subprocess.check_output`, rather than directly calling `subprocess.Popen`.